# can't get htaccess to work with all my commands

Tags: php, .htaccess

Here's what I need to happen:

1. Set the site home directory to "/home"
2. For database-driven pages, convert "index.php?page=" (if the link goes to "/about", it invisibly converts it to "index.php?page=about")
3. For NON-database-driven pages, simply remove the ".php" from the link ("/about.php" goes to "/about")

I have it working fine with the ISS installation with web.config, but I can't translate it very well to .htaccess. Here's what I have so far:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On

#Alternate default index page
DirectoryIndex index.php?page=home

# Send would-be 404 requests to Craft
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule (.+) index.php?page=$1 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule    "^/index\.php$"  "/index.php?page=home" [PT]

RewriteRule ^/?([^/d]+)/?$ index.php?page=$1 [L,QSA]


AddCharset UTF-8 .php
ErrorDocument 404 /404.php 

</IfModule>
```

With the htaccess code above, 3) is fine, but the other two don't work.

Can anyone help this noob out? I'm on Godaddy hosting, if that makes a difference. Also, this site is deep within a testing sub-sub-subdirectory, so any root directs won't work.

UPDATE:

I was able to get SOMETHING going by adding the full url to the RewriteRule -

```
AddCharset UTF-8 .php
RewriteEngine On

#Alternate default index page
RewriteRule ^home/?$ http://example.com/test/site/index.php?page=home [L,QSA,NC]
RewriteRule ^/?$ http://example.com/test/site/home [L,QSA,NC]


# add .php extension if corresponding file exists
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ $1 [L]

# everything else
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule (.+) http://example.com/test/site/index.php?page=$1 [QSA,L]
```

but now it sort of does the opposite of what I want it to; rather than going to "example.com/test/site/about", it rewrites it to go to "example.com/test/site/index.php?page=about"

UPDATE 2:

Final working version in case anyone else runs into the same issue:

```
AddCharset UTF-8 .php
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /test/site/

#Alternate default index page
RewriteRule ^home/?$ index.php?page=home [L,QSA,NC]
RewriteRule ^/?$ /home [L,QSA,NC]
DirectoryIndex index.php?page=home


# everything else
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule (.+) index.php?page=$1 [QSA,L]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have it this way:

```
AddCharset UTF-8 .php
RewriteEngine On

#Alternate default index page
RewriteRule ^home/?$ index.php?page=home [L,QSA,NC]

# add .php extension if corresponding file exists
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ $1.php [L]

# everything else
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule (.+) index.php?page=$1 [QSA,L]
```

`ErrorDocument` won't be needed because every non-file, non-dir anyway goes to `index.php?page=...`

Comment: Still doesn't seem to work. Does the Godaddy hosting have anything to do  with it? I saw on another page that
    #Fix Rewrite
    Options -Multiviews
had to be added before my mod_rewrite directives
https://davidwalsh.name/mod_rewrite-htaccess-godaddy

Comment: well it's not redirecting, I get redirected back to my root domain 404

Comment: "/index.php?page=about" works fine, but "/about" returns the 404.

Random garbage gives me an Internal Server Error

Comment: No, it gives me a 404 as well. Although, as I mentioned, this is in a sub-sub-subdirectory (example.com/test/site/index.php), if that's making a difference.

Comment: That is correct. Furthermore, example.com/test/site/index.php?page=home also gives me a 404, even though example.com/test/site/index.php?page=about works fine

Comment: If `example.com/test/site/index.php?page=home` gives 404 then problem is your GoDady setup or code. Try to talk to support team.

Comment: Using `full url` will redirect `example.com/test/site/home` to `example.com/test/site/index.php?page=home` and show your internal URL in browser. Try using `RewriteBase /test/site/` after `RewriteEngine On` line and make sure to replace `/test/site/` with your actual dir path

Comment: Awesome, that fixed the 404 errors, but visually, I was still getting "index.php?page=about" when I typed in "/about". Looked closer at what you gave me, and took out the "# add .php extension if corresponding file exists" bit, and that fixed it right up :) Thanks for your help!